# Loopback version vs loopback cli version

Tags: loopback4

I have a existing loopback application with @loopback/core version 2.1.0 and @loopback/cli version 2.1.1. I am not able to create controllers or datasources using commandline with lb command. When I upgrade the loopback/cli version to 3.1.1, I was able to use the command lb4 to create controllers and datasources but there are some dependency version incompatibilities. Can some one suggest how to use command lines with loopback/cli version 2.1.1. Also, how are loopback and loopback/cli versions are related(because loopback 4 is still using loopback/cli version 3.1.1).
Below are the package dependencies of my project.
"@loopback/boot": "^2.0.1",
"@loopback/context": "^3.1.0",
"@loopback/core": "^2.1.0",
"@loopback/openapi-v3": "^3.1.0",
"@loopback/repository": "^2.0.1",
"@loopback/rest": "^3.0.1",
"@loopback/rest-explorer": "^2.0.1",
"@loopback/service-proxy": "^2.0.1",
"config": "^3.3.1",
"express": "^4.17.1",
"loopback-connector-rest": "^3.7.0",
"node-fetch": "^2.6.1",
"p-event": "^4.1.0",
"snyk": "^1.305.0",
"tslib": "^1.10.0"

Answer (score 0):

loopback cli maintains a **list of all the packages and its versions** that are needed. So if we those are not compatible with the one that we are using then the error comes up. so you can use the **update** command to initially update the version of exsiting dependencies and then try creating the controllers and datasources. Refer https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Update-generator.html.